# How can i make an input box value = a string?

Tags: c#

How can i make a string = a form input box value in c#?
For example, someone enters their username as Bob.
Then the string value User is Bob.

Comment: You should try doing a search before posting a question like this. You would find an answer faster than it took the time to come here and post.

Answer (score 3):

Easy like this:

```
string text = YourInputBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following possibilities:

1. [DataBinding](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html);
2. TextBox [`TextChanged`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textchanged) event;

Answer (score 1):

```
string user = MyUsernameTextBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = this.userNameTextBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

In your code behind file:

```
User myUser = new User();
myUser.Username = txtName.Text;
```

User class:

```
public class User
{
     public string Username {get;set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want some thing like this.

```
String a="";
a=txtYourInputBoxId.Text
```